# Covering full page on dragover

Tags: css, drag-and-drop

I got drag and drop to work nicely in my web application, but there is a problem I am not able to solve: I searched around and I found *similar* questions, also a few having referring to *the opposite* of my problem, but I wasn't able to understand what is going on.

The problem concerns the visual effect on dragover. On the dragover event, I add a `dragging` class which has a `:before` element, set in a way which *should* cover all the body, but as a matter of fact it only covers the viewport, so that if I scroll the window the rest of the body is *not* covered. Here is the CSS I used:

```
.dragging:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 200;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

I also created [a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/OneiroDancer/v7bu6czy/8/); for the sake of simplicity, I bound the addition of the class to the `click` event. If you click on the yellow body it gets slightly darker; if you scroll down, you'll see the regular backgrund reappearing. In my application, I cannot click on the content of the page below the div, but if I scroll down I can click on the remaining content.

The "opposite" of my problem I mentioned above was that somebody wanted to a div to cover the viewport rather than the full body, and he was suggested to use 100vh rather than 100%, so I guess there is something I am missing...

Comment: So you want to cover the whole content with darker background ?

Comment: Covering the content and, first and foremost, prevent the user from clicking on anything on the main page: that's a modal popup. I know, there are many many components aroud doing the same, but everytime I try to use them I find I cannot do simple customization, so I'm using as few external dependancies as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

### a. The general case

Parent (i.e. `.draggable`):

```
{
  position:relative
}
```

Child (i.e. `.draggable::before`):

```
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

It's *general* in the sense your parent can be any element, have any size. It works as long as there is no other intermediate *positioned* element between parent and child (where *positioned* means having a set `position` value other than default one - `static`; if such an element exists, it will become the parent/reference element).

### b. The exception (the viewport)

Sometimes it makes more sense give the child the size of the viewport instead of the size of its closest *positioned* ancestor in DOM. In this case, all you need is to apply the following to child (and the parent will be the viewport):

```
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width; 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* you could also use right:0; bottom:0;, as above
   * you don't need to set width and height 
   * but, since it was present in your code, I used it
   */
}
```

Please note the viewport is not always the browser window. For example, 3d transformed elements act as viewports for their children.

---

In your case, the general case would be: https://jsfiddle.net/v7bu6czy/11/

```js
$("body").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("body").addClass('dragging');
        console.log('using position:absolute (general solution), ::before height is: ' + window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.dragging'), ':before').height)
    });
```

```css
body { 
  margin: 0; 
}

.longdiv {
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.dragging {
  position: relative;
}
.dragging:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head lang="en">
</head><body>
<div class="longdiv">

</div>
</body>
```

And the exception would be: https://jsfiddle.net/v7bu6czy/9/

```js
$("body").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("body").addClass('dragging');
        console.log('using position:fixed, ::before height is: ' + window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.dragging'), ':before').height)
    });
```

```css
html, body, document { height: 100%; margin: 0; }

.longdiv {
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.dragging:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 200;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head lang="en">
</head><body>
<div class="longdiv">

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: @FrancescoMarchetti-Stasi, you're welcome. By the way, technically, it's not doing what you asked for. It's not covering the entire page. It just covers the entire viewport but it's attached to the viewport so it doesn't matter where you are in the page.

Comment: I hadn't thought I could do that, and the effect is nice: the page scrolls, but the covering div stays fixed. Still, I wonder, is there a way to make a div the full size of the body?

Comment: We commented at the same time :)

Comment: Yes, you'd need to the parent `position:relative;` and the child (`before`)  `top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;`. That should do it. See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/v7bu6czy/11/

Comment: Well, I had tried to follow your suggestion without success, so when I added the link I went to check how it worked, but I'm afraid you posted the wrong link, it's the same as in the previous comment! My problem is fully solved by your first answer, now we are just digging for curiosity :)

Comment: The links are good: [/11/](https://jsfiddle.net/v7bu6czy/11/) is making the child same height as parent and has `position:absolute`. [/9/](https://jsfiddle.net/v7bu6czy/9/)  is using `position:fixed` and the child has height of viewport.

Comment: Yesss, now I see! Thanks again :)

Comment: Rewrote the answer to make it clearer and hopefully more helpful for future visitors.